# how to call javascript from code behind in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

i have java script in my page and i want to call it from vb.net code behind from function AND didn't want to call it (onload or onclick or any similar event) but i want to call it from function doing looping.so it will be run more one time

Comment: ?! ...Do you have a code snipped / example of what you try to do?

Comment: Younds like you did not understand the difference between clientside and serverside code.

Comment: This is not possible. Code behind = server side, javascript = client side.

Comment: example:  in my page aspx i add javascript that get value of element by id <script type="javascript">function getval(elemntid)  mycode;</script>  and in my vbcode the function is : public function() for i = 0 to 5 (i want to call javascript here...) next i end function

Comment: this is most certainly possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it like this:

```
 ' Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page. 
    Dim csname1 As [String] = "PopupScript"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.[GetType]()

    ' Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class. 
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

    ' Check to see if the startup script is already registered. 
    If Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1) Then
        Dim cstext1 As New StringBuilder()
        cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> getval('elementid') </") 'Your javascript function
        cstext1.Append("script>")

        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString())
    End If
```

[Source.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx#Y878)

Comment: Whomever downvoted this had no reason to do it. This is exactly what the OP is asking and it will definitely work.

Comment: thanks,but can i use it direct in my function in behind code to run it or putting it in page load to register it only

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible using SignalR.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Very cool stuff.

A persistent connection sounds like it would do what you are looking for.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't understand how can i use it in my problem